# Is there a way to inject EntityManager into a service

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

While using `Symfony 3.3`, I am declaring a service like this:

```
class TheService implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
    ...
}
```

Inside each action where I need the EntityManager, I get it from the container:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

This is a bit annoying, so I'm curious whether Symfony has something that acts like `EntityManagerAwareInterface`.

Comment: a quick google search would have been faster than actually typing this question

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Traditionally, you would have created a new service definition in your `services.yml` file set the `entity manager` as argument to your constructor

```
app.the_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\TheService
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

More recently, with the release of Symfony 3.3, the default symfony-standard-edition changed their default `services.yml` file to default to using `autowire` and add all classes in the `AppBundle` to be services. This removes the need for adding the custom service and using a type hint in your constructor will automatically inject the right service.

Your service class would then look like the following:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class TheService
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // ...
}
```

For more information about automatically defining service dependencies, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

The new default `services.yml` configuration file is available here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.3/app/config/services.yml

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to inject Repositories instead of EntityManager?

Comment: @user3429660 Autowiring works for the repositories too

Comment: Note that, at least in my case, the important thing is to autowire `EntityManagerInterface` instead of `EntityManager` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I inject the EM into a service on the container like this in services.yml:

```
 application.the.service:
      class: path\to\te\Service
      arguments:
        entityManager: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

And then on the service class get it on the __construct method.
Hope it helps.

Comment: *Small note:* In the parameter list of the `__construct` method there must be a parameter named `$entityManager`, otherwise Symfony don't know which one to use for argument `entityManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and solved it by editing the migration code.

I replaced

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL');
```

by

```php
$this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "-"');
```

I don't know why `bin/console make:entity` doesn't prompt us to provide a default in those cases. Django does it and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to answer your subquestion:

> This is a bit annoying, so I'm curious whether Symfony has something
> that acts like EntityManagerAwareInterface.

And I think there is a solution to do so (I use it myself).
The idea is that you slightly change your kernel so tha it checks for all services which implement the `EntityManagerAwareInterface` and injects it for them.

You can also add write an `EntityManagerAwareTrait` that implements the `$entityManager` property and the `setEntityManager()`setter. The only thing left after that is to implement/use the interface/trait couple the way you would do for the Logger for example.

(you could have done this through a compiler pass as well).

```
<?php
// src/Kernel.php

namespace App;

use App\Entity\EntityManagerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use function array_key_exists;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $definitions = $container->getDefinitions();
        foreach ($definitions as $definition) {
            if (!$this->isAware($definition, EntityManagerAwareInterface::class)) {
                continue;
            }
            $definition->addMethodCall('setEntityManager', [$container->getDefinition('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')]);
        }
    }

    private function isAware(Definition $definition, string $awarenessClass): bool
    {
        $serviceClass = $definition->getClass();
        if ($serviceClass === null) {
            return false;
        }
        $implementedClasses = @class_implements($serviceClass, false);
        if (empty($implementedClasses)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (array_key_exists($awarenessClass, $implementedClasses)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The interface:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

interface EntityManagerAwareInterface
{
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): void;
}
```

The trait:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

trait EntityManagerAwareTrait
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    protected $entityManager;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): void
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
}
```

And now you can use it:

```
    <?php
    
    // src/SomeService.php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace App;
    
    use Exception;
    use App\Entity\EntityManagerAwareInterface;
    use App\Entity\Entity\EntityManagerAwareTrait;
    use App\Entity\Entity\User;
    
    class SomeService implements EntityManagerAwareInterface
    {
        use EntityManagerAwareTrait;

        public function someMethod()
        {    
           $users = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::Class)->findAll();
           // ...
        }
    }
```