# How can I use doctrine method inside my service (Symfony 4)?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created my first own service in Symfony :

```
// src/Service/PagesGenerator.php
```

```
namespace App\Service;

class PagesGenerator
{
    public function getPages()
    {

      $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);

        $messages = [
            'You did it! You updated the system! Amazing!',
            'That was one of the coolest updates I\'ve seen all day!',
            'Great work! Keep going!',
        ];

        $index = array_rand($messages);

        return $messages[$index];
    }
}
```

But I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class
>   "App\Service\PagesGenerator".

I tried then to add in my services.yaml:

```
PagesGenerator:
    class: %PagesGenerator.class%
    arguments:
      - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

But then I get the error message:

> The file "/Users/work/project/config/services.yaml" does not contain
>   valid YAML in /Users/work/project/config/services.yaml (which is
>   loaded in resource "/Users/work/project/config/services.yaml").

Comment: Symfony is working with the magic pattern called Dependency Injection. Instead of giving any argument to your service in `services.yaml`, call `__construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)` in your service and let Symfony inject your entity manager. It's much clearer in my opinion.

Comment: @GasKa Thank you very much. This sounds really good. Can you give an example. I tried to put this line into my service but I get the error `syntax error, unexpected '$em' `

Comment: I think you used `$em` instead of `$this->em`. Also, you have to declare this property for your service before `__construct()`.

Comment: @GasKa Ok, I am not exactly knowing how to do it, but I try and let you know if it worked

Comment: I'll make a reply instead of comment for that. Check it out in few minutes.

Comment: As I said my answer in your previous question: read the documentation. Using Autowiring is part of the Symfony Best Practices.

Comment: But not reading the documentation? Again: use autowiring.

Comment: @StephanVierkant Yes but first I needed to figure out where to create the class. So I did a tutorial and wanted to get the tutorial work and understand, before I go to the next step understand "autowiring"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, in comments I was saying that is better to let Symfony doing his job and autowiring `EntityManager`. This is what you should do. Also, can you tell us what Symfony version are you using and if autowiring is enabled (check services.yaml for that)?

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class PagesGenerator
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getPages()
    {

      $page = $this->em->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);

        $messages = [
            'You did it! You updated the system! Amazing!',
            'That was one of the coolest updates I\'ve seen all day!',
            'Great work! Keep going!',
        ];

        $index = array_rand($messages);

        return $messages[$index];
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds about right but what'd happen if i need to call another Manager to get my Repository? since EntityManagerInterface doesn't have a getManager() attribute i can only call the repository from the 'default'. If i try to do a $this->getDoctrine() from a Service i get an error :: Call to a member function has() on null

Answer (score 3):

With Symfony 4 and the new autowiring you can easily inject certain number of class

To find out, which classes/interface you can use for autowiring, use this command:

```
bin/console   debug:autowiring
```

We are going to use this one :

> Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface
>   (doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager)

So let's make it, add this just before getPages function

```
/**
 * @var EntityManagerInterface
 */
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
  $page = $this->em->getRepository(Pages::class)->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you! Working well

Answer (score 1):

make sure you use proper indent using "spaces" for YAML.

> A YAML file use spaces as indentation, you can use 2 or 4 spaces for
>   indentation, but no tab
>   [**read more about this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975954/a-yaml-file-cannot-contain-tabs-as-indentation)

**Before symfony 3.3**

for example we have service `sms_manager` in `AppBundle/FrontEndBundle/Services`

```
services:
    AppBundle.sms_manager:
        class: AppBundle\FrontEndBundle\Services\SmsManager
        arguments: [ '@service_container' ,'@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' ]
```

then your service can receive your arguments in constructor

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\FrontEndBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;

class SmsManager {
    private $container;
    private $DM;

    public function __construct( Container $container, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $DM ) 
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->DM        = $DM;
    }

    /**
    * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
    */

    public function getDoctrine() {
      return $this->DM;
    }

}
```

**With Symfony 3.3 or more,**

[Is there a way to inject EntityManager into a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809739/is-there-a-way-to-inject-entitymanager-into-a-service)

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface

class PagesGenerator
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I know that it's not recommended anymore to inject your container. But this is recommended starting with Symfony 4.x. Anyway, avoid this

Comment: @GasKa he didn't mentioned the version.

Comment: Correctly, I assumed he has Symfony 3.x or Symfony 4.x and everything works as I said. I saw that you edited your post. Good! Let's see his reply firstly

Comment: I am using Symfony 4